# How to vertically align elements of legend box

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below *ggplot*

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
theme_set(theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(0,1),
        legend.justification = c(0,1),
        legend.box.margin = margin(5, l = 5, unit = 'mm'),
        legend.box = 'horizontal'
        ))

ggplot(diamonds,aes(x,y,color=z))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_colour_gradient2('Time [min]',
                         low='lightgray',
                         mid='red3',
                         high='red4',
                         midpoint=15)
```

With this I am getting below plot,

[image]

However I wanted to **horizontally** align the *colour definition* in the legend, while *colour title (i.e. Time [min])* should be on top of the *colour definition*. Is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `legend.direction = 'horizontal'` and some `guide`s,

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(x,y,color=z))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_colour_gradient2('Time [min]',
                         low='lightgray',
                         mid='red3',
                         high='red4',
                         midpoint=15) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(0,1),
        legend.justification = c(0,1),
        legend.box.margin = margin(5, l = 5, unit = 'mm'),
        legend.box = 'horizontal',
        legend.direction = 'horizontal'
  ) +
  guides(colour = guide_colourbar(title.position="top", title.hjust = 0.5),
         size = guide_legend(title.position="top", title.hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]